# Javascript Click Button

Tags: javascript

I have a button on a webpage with the following inspection:

`<button type="button" class="odd-item-dropdown-confirm" data-qa="button-odd-item-dropdown-confirm">Confirm</button>`

I would like to click on this button, I tried:

```
function clickConfirm(){
  var bntConfirm = document.querySelector('.btn.button-odd-item-dropdown-confirm');
  bntConfirm.click();
}

clickConfirm();
```

And got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null`

Comment: Cannot read property 'click' of null, it means it can't match the element, you need to use the name of the html element, for example button.className. also you made mstake at selecting querySelector.

Comment: If you look at my inspection, the class does exist, I tried with both 'class' and 'data-qa',none work but inspecting the element in developer mode you can see that it does exist, look at the first code in my question

Comment: As has been stated many times (in multiple answers), no the class does NOT exist

Comment: In your example too, the button doesn't have classes named `btn` and `button-odd-item-dropdown-confirm` and so `document.querySelector('.btn.button-odd-item-dropdown-confirm')` is not finding the targetted button element that you are expecting. There is `odd-item-dropdown-confirm` only, and *querySelector* doesn't track whatever there is inside `data-qa` attribute like you've written.

Comment: ok I see now, thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It says what it means: the query is not matching any element and returning `null`. If you look at your HTML, there is no class `button-odd-item-dropdown-confirm`.

You should be selecting using this selector: `button.odd-item-dropdown-confirm`. See proof-of-concept:

```js
// Checking
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('I am clicked');
});

clickConfirm();
function clickConfirm(){

    var bntConfirm = document.querySelector('button.odd-item-dropdown-confirm');
    bntConfirm.click();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="odd-item-dropdown-confirm" data-qa="button-odd-item-dropdown-confirm">Confirm</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
clickConfirm();
function clickConfirm(){

    var bntConfirm = document.querySelector('.odd-item-dropdown-confirm');
    bntConfirm.click();
}
```

I think this should work if you haven't used this class anywhere else, but you can always use Ids, or other things to identify the button properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your selected class is not the correct one.

```
    clickConfirm();
    function clickConfirm(){

        var bntConfirm = document.querySelector('.odd-item-dropdown-confirm');
        bntConfirm.click();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a problem in your code:
`var bntConfirm = document.querySelector('.btn.button-odd-item-dropdown-confirm');`

you don't have `.btn` class anywhere

you don't have `.button-odd-item-dropdown-confirm` class anywhere

Take a look at the solutions that can work

```js
clickConfirm();
function clickConfirm(){
    // this will not work.
    // var bntConfirm = document.querySelector('.btn.button-odd-item-dropdown-confirm');
    // you don't have .btn class anywhere
    // you don't have .button-odd-item-dropdown-confirm class anywhere
    /* --------------------- */
    
    // select by class
    var bntConfirm = document.querySelector('.odd-item-dropdown-confirm');
    bntConfirm.click();
    
    // or select by data attr
    var bntConfirm = document.querySelector('*[data-qa="button-odd-item-dropdown-confirm"]');
    bntConfirm.click();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="odd-item-dropdown-confirm" data-qa="button-odd-item-dropdown-confirm">Confirm</button>
```